# PHP: Weekly and Every Other Week Scheduling (Predetermined)

Tags: php, mysql, scheduling

I have a question regarding a project I'm taking over.  I'm converting a MS Access application that someone else wrote and converting it to a MySQL/PHP web app.  Most of it has been completed, however, I'm at a standstill when it comes to the scheduling part of this application.

I need to be able to have a "schedule" for work to be done.  So, I would run a report, and it would search the database for a certain day, for example, March 15, 2011.  It would build this based on database records for THAT day, and would build a report on it optimized for printing.

The application itself was originally written for MS Access, so therefore, by default, MS ACCESS allows for GUI copy/paste.  With that being said, the way that the scheduling was done by the end user is, they would copy/paste from a template to build the "weekly" schedule for THAT particular customer.  For example, say theres a new customer that signs up for weekly, the end user would go to a template (MS Access) copy all the rows that would predefined as "every week" and then paste it into the customer's section.

Obviously, I don't want, nor should I go that route.

What I'm wanting to know, since this is the biggest project I've ever done, and I am doing this freelance (I do programming as a hobby - and this is a favor), is if anyone could point me into a direction that would get my on the right track.

The "customers" are either going to be on a "weekly" schedule or an "every other week" schedule.  In the database, there is a "current_schedule" option that tells me if they are "weekly" or "every other week", but it would be nice to have the webapp actually "build" out the schedule based on that, almost like "upcoming appointments" or something like that.  I've seen this done before, but I just don't know the logic or the direction to go in.  Additionally, I will want to reschedule certain items, which that should be easy once I get a basic understanding of my previous question on building the schedules and displaying them on the screen.

The only thing I can currently think of is building a script that would get the database option, and then "build" the schedules into the database.  Problem with that is, if I want to change a customer, and then the "scheuduler builder" is run again, it will mess everything up - or I could build a check into that, that would check to see if it was already build and then "protect" that customer from being rebuilt, but it seems like more work than needed.  I could be wrong, and that's why I'm looking to you guys to at least give me some ideas.

Thanks in advanced, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP/MySQL app is on windows, you should use task scheduler to run a perl or PHP script every week, to check what needs to be updated in the database, and to do it. I recommend Strawberry Perl, the perl interpreter for windows. You simply install it, [install the DBI module,](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/perlmysql.htm) and run your updates through that script which is scheduled by the OS to run weekly. The script would run diffeent tasks based on what it saw in the database.

If the setup is on a UNIX machine, the you would do the exact same thing, except that instead of scheduling a weekly running of a perl script through "Task Scheduler", you would do it through cron. See `man crontab` or `man cron`. The perl interpreter is built into every UNIX system, so you would only need to make sure the DBI module is installed. That's how I have always run periodic tasks on my databases: **scheduled scripts through the OS.**

Comment: I'm a *nix systems administrator, so I'm definitely doing this on a *nix system, and I know cron would do the scheduling.  With that being said, is this the way to go?  Was my direction or creating a build script the way to go, or is there another "better" or more "optimized" was of doing this?

Comment: I have never heard of any other way of scheduling tasks other than through the OS, unless you know of a specialized daemon to do the same thing, or unless you wish to write a daemon. Cron is much easier, better documented, and better logged. It is the way I always use to schedule tasks, including the update of some of my databases. :)

Comment: I never asked about scheduling in the OS.  I'm writing a PHP application that schedules in itself.  Nothing to do with cron or anything.  Think of it as you going to the doctors office and they ask you what time you prefer to set up your next appointment - same thing.  I'm wanting to know if anyone knows of a good way to create a scheduling application the way I need it above. It's for scheduling work/jobs.